# ajax не отправляет переменные формы

Tags: php, ajax

```
           <form  method="post" id="form3">
              <input  type="text" name="name"/>
              <input type="text"name="phone"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Отправить">             
           </form>
```

Скрипт

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#form3").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "post.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Спасибо");
    });
    return false;
 });

});
```

файл обработчик `post.php`

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];   
$headers = 'Content-type:text/plain; Charset=utf-8';    

$result = "My name: ".$name."\nMy phone: ".$phone;

$subject = "message from the site"; 

mail('pupckin@out.com', $subject, $result, $headers);
?>
```

Срабатывает mail() и приходит только $result без переменных из $_POST

Comment: ну так откройте network вкладку и смотрите serialize сработал скорее всего нет, так как this здесь не тот который ожидаеться. Должно сработать `function(e){}` где `e` элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас у формы нет сабмита. А действие висит на сабмит форы.

```
<form  method="post" action='t3.php' id="form3">
    <input  type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="phone"/>
    <input type="submit">      
</form>
```

Немного исправил js: появились функции при успехе, ошибке. Сделал вывод в консоль браузера.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form3").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result){console.log(result)},
            error: function(err){console.log(err);}
        }).done(function() {
            console.log("Спасибо");
        });
    });
});
```

На стороне php нужно сделать проверки существования переменных - как минимум.

Comment: спешил не указал, есть сабмит, как же я без него отправляю форму.

Comment: я у себя код выполнил - всё работает.

Comment: @Proshka в 2017 давным давно для отправки данных наличие `submit` не требуется.. более того, сам  `form` давно не нужен. просто к сведению

Comment: @Proshka сделал исправления (исправил и HTML и js). Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Proshka ну что? Работает?

Comment: все работает, спасибо